# routes to manage groups and permissions with rest api endpoints in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to manage groups and permissions with `django-rest-framework` API endpoints?

I want to have all functionalities that `admin panel` has to manage groups and permissions, **in some API routes**.

Thanks in advance

**My Implementation:**

I ended up our requirement with these `serializers` and `viewsets` :

*SERIALIZERS:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Permission
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'codename',)


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'permissions',)


class CreateGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    permission_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, write_only=True, queryset=Permission.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'permissions', 'permission_ids',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        permission_ids = validated_data.pop('permission_ids')
        group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
        group.permissions.set(permission_ids)
        return group
```

*VIEWSETS:*

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission

class UserViewSet(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    """
    Manage users
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=['get', 'post'],
    )
    def groups(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # TODO: set user groups
            return Response({})
        return Response(GroupSerializer(Group.objects.filter(user=request.user), many=True).data)

    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=['get', 'post'],
    )
    def permissions(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # TODO: set user permissions
            return Response({})

        user = request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            permissions = Permission.objects.all()
        else:
            permissions = list(user.user_permissions.all() | Permission.objects.filter(group__user=user))
        return Response(PermissionSerializer(permissions, many=True).data)


class GroupViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    """
    Manage user groups
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateGroupSerializer
        return GroupSerializer
```

If you have a better solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: According to the `django-rest-framework` [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions) the best way is [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Dad `django-guardian` is for per object permissions. this can't help me

Comment: @Community I added my implementation.

Comment: @HamidRasti How would you set user groups and permissions in given example?

Comment: Somthing like this: `request.user.permissions.set(permission_ids)`,  permission_ids is read from validated data of serializer. @NewtonKaranu

Answer (score 0):

You implementation works well.
By the way, it only allows group name update so I suggest that we can implement update logic also as Django admin panel has.

```py
class CreateGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        permission_ids = validated_data.pop("permission_ids")
        instance.permissions.set(permission_ids)
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
...
```

```py
class GroupViewSet(ModelViewSet):
...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ["POST", "PUT"]:
            return CreateGroupSerializer
        return GroupSerializer
...
```